# Explode json object into multiple fields with ElasticSearch and Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, pm2, filebeat

Moving forward with my love-hate relationship with ElasticSearch, I am trying to log information from pm2 (nodejs) to my elastic search cluster.

Current setup is as follows:

Pm2 manages some node apps and it is configured to log into json. This is an example:

```
{"message":"{\n  \"className\": \"AppointmentBot\",\n  \"dialog\": \"query\",\n  \"step\": 2,\n  \"millis\": 1497,\n  \"extra\": \"\",\n  \"type\": \"logger\",\n  \"level\": \"info\",\n  \"message\": \"Client\",\n  \"timestamp\": \"08-01-2018 22:44:22 +00:00\"\n}\n","timestamp":"2018-01-08T22:44:22.350Z","type":"out","process_id":9,"app_name":"Chatbot-App-Dev"}
```

Filebeat configuration

```
type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
    /home/app/.pm2/logs/*.log
  fields:
    type: pm2
```

Logstash config:

```
if [fields][type] == "pm2" {
        json {
            source => "message"
            remove_field => ["message"]
        } 

        date {
            match => [ "timestamp", "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssZ" ]
            tag_on_failure => ["_dateparsefailure"]
        }
    }
```

This produces something like this in Kibana/ElasticSearch:

```
{
  "className": "AppointmentBot",
  "dialog": "query",
  "step": 2,
  "millis": 1497,
  "extra": "",
  "type": "logger",
  "level": "info",
  "message": "Client",
  "timestamp": "08-01-2018 22:44:22 +00:00"
}
```

Now, what I want is to have those JSON fields not in one single field, but each on one single field.

Some caveats:

- I don't want to use a hardcoded mutate and I think this can be solved with it, because I don't want to hardcode the fields. Sometimes the object could be different.

Basically, I want to parse the json, and each field add it as a new field in the index. Could be a structure or all the fields in the root, I don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it with some help from Elastic support. The problem was that if you want to reference fields inside logstash configuration, you need to use the [A][B] notation. Basically, my second filter was not running because I was using pm2.message.

This is my final configuration, which works:

```
json {
            source => "message"
            target => "[pm2]"
            remove_field => "message"
            skip_on_invalid_json => true
        }

        if "_jsonparsefailure" not in [tags]  {
            json {
                source => "[pm2][message]"
                target => "[pm2][data]"
                remove_field => "[pm2][message]"
                skip_on_invalid_json => true
            }
        }
```